# Central limit theorem with a biased dice

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

We want to know the prbabiltiy $p \in (0,1)$ that a biased die rolls a $6$.  We roll the die $n$ independent times
$X_i=\begin{cases} 
 1 & \textrm{if the i-th roll is a 6} \\ 
 0 & \textrm{else} \\ 
\end{cases}
$
calculate with the clt the approximate min. number of rolls so that $p$ can be estimated with $\bar{X_n}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and a uncertainty of $0,01$ with a probability of min. $0,9$.

Therefore I have to calculate $P(|\bar X_n-p|\le 0.01)\ge 0.9$

If I use $S=\sum X_i=n\bar X_n$ we have $P(|\frac{\sum X_i}{n}-p|\le 0.01)\ge 0.9$

But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Do you mean that you have to find the minimal $n$ such that P$(|\bar X_n-p|\le 0.01) \geq 0.9$?

Comment: Yes, thats what I tried to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the central limit theorem means using $\ \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2\right)\ $ to approximate the distribution of $\ 
\overline{X}_n\ $, where $\ \mu_n\ $ is the mean of $\ 
\overline{X}_n\ $ and $\ \sigma_n^2\ $ is its variance. What *are* its mean and variance?

**Reply to query from OP:** Since
\begin{align}
P\left(\left|\,\overline{X}_n-p\,\right|\le 0.01\right)&=P\left(-0.01\le\overline{X}_n-p\le 0.01\right)\\
&=P\left(-\frac{0.01}{\sigma_n}\le\frac{\overline{X}_n-p}{\sigma_n}\le \frac{0.01}{\sigma_n}\right)\\
&\approx{\cal N}(0,1)\left(\frac{0.01}{\sigma_n}\right)-{\cal N}(0,1)\left(-\frac{0.01}{\sigma_n}\right)\\
&=2{\cal N}(0,1)\left(0.01\sqrt\frac{n}{p(1-p)}\right)-1\ ,
\end{align}
and $\  {\cal N}(0,1)\ $ is a strictly increasing function, you need to find the (unique) $\ x\ $ such that $\ {\cal N}(0,1)\left(x\right)=\frac{1+0.9}{2}=0.95\ $.  The value of $\ n\ $ you want is then the smallest integer such that $\ 0.01\sqrt\frac{n}{p(1-p)}\ge x\ $—that is, such that $\ n\ge 10000\,p(1-p)x^2\ $.

Comment: Can  I say that with the The strong law of large numbers the mean $\mu_n$ is  Bernoulli distribution mean $p$ and $\ \sigma_n^2\=p(1-p)$?

Comment: Yes, for each $\ i\ $ $\ X_i\ $ has a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with mean $\ p\ $ and variance $\ p(1-p)\ $.  However, you want the mean and variance of $\ \overline{X}_n\ $. Now, $\ n\overline{X}_n\ $  has the [binomial distribution $\ B(n,p)\ $](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which reduces to the Bernoulli when $\ n=1\ $, and which has mean $\ np\ $ and variance $\ n p(1-p)\ $.

Comment: Dividing $\ n\overline{X}_n\ $ by $\ n\ $ reduces its mean by a factor of $\ n\ $, and its variance by a factor of $\ n^2\ $, giving $\ \overline{X}_n\ $ a mean of $\ p\ $ and a variance of $\ \frac{p(1-p)}{n}\ $.

Comment: can you explain me, why it is a factor of $n^2$ when we calculate the variance?
thank u very much

Comment: By definition, the variance of a random variable $\ X\ $ is $\ \sigma_X^2=E\left((X-E(X))^2\right)\ $. For any $\ a\ $, therefore, the variance of $\ aX\ $ is $\ E\left((aX-E(aX))^2\right)= E\left(a^2(X-E(X))^2\right)=$$a^2E\left((X-E(X))^2\right)=a^2\sigma_X^2\ $.

Comment: ohh, thans a lot !

Comment: So now I have to put the mean and variance in here  \ \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2\right)\ to put it in here (|\bar X_n-p|\le 0.01) \geq 0.9?